# How to trim within the WHERE clause of an SQL statement?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I am trying to use a *datetime* column in an SQL database to retrieve rows who's **Start_Time** date is equal to a certain value.

Here is my current SQL:

```
Select Job_Type
FROM Shift
WHERE Start_Time IN (SELECT DISTINCT CAST(Start_Time AS DATE) As Start_Time
                     FROM Shift)
```

The **Start_Time** column stores like so: 26/05/2017 16:06:00

The subquery above returns the date like so: 26/05/2017.

I want the outer SELECT statement to retrieve rows who's **Start_Time** begins with the same "date" (26/05/2017), and I want to disregard the time aspect for now.

At the moment, this is failiing because of the `WHERE Start_Time` piece of code. It isn't trimming off the time part of the column at the moment.

Can you guys tell me how to remove the time aspect within the WHERE clause?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Shift] (
[Shift_Id]    INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Start_Time]  DATETIME      NOT NULL,
[End_Time]    DATETIME      NOT NULL,
[Job_Type]    NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Employee_Id] INT           NOT NULL,
[Available]   INT           NULL,
FOREIGN KEY ([Employee_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee] ([Employee_Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Also, below is my full code:

```
   protected void repFullSchedule_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            Repeater jobRepeater = (Repeater)e.Item.FindControl("repJobs");
            string Start_time = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Start_Time").ToString();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Job_Type FROM Shift WHERE cast(Start_Time as date) IN (SELECT DISTINCT CAST(Start_Time AS DATE) As Start_Time FROM Shift)", con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);




            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            jobRepeater.DataSource = dt;
            jobRepeater.DataBind();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't get the structure of the query.  If you do what you want, you will return all rows in `shift`.  Also, what is the type of `Start_Time`?  Is it a date/time or a string?

Comment: 'Start_Time' is a datetime. I've posted additional code above to try to clarify the question. Above, _repFullSchedule_ is a repeater which displays the 'Start_Time' of each row in the database in the form of "Friday 26/05/2017". Then inside the inner repeater (jobRepeater), I want to display all the 'Job_Type's who are associated with the various 'Start_Time's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
Select Job_Type FROM Shift WHERE cast(Start_Time as date) IN (SELECT DISTINCT CAST(Start_Time AS DATE) As Start_Time FROM Shift)
```

else

```
Select Job_Type FROM Shift WHERE cast(convert(varchar(10),Start_Time,101) as date) IN (SELECT DISTINCT CAST(convert(varchar(10),Start_Time,101) AS DATE) As Start_Time FROM Shift)
```

Comment: Hi Ravi, Thanks for the help. I am trying to display employee shifts. I currently have an outer repeater, which displays the dates where there are upcoming shifts. The above SQL is for the inner repeater. I want this repeater to display the job_types associated with the dates from the outer repeater. Your SQL above displays _all_ job types for all of the days. So rather than appear for the day associated, it appears on all days. Regardless of whether or not they're linked in the table

Comment: If this isn't clear, can we move this conversation to chat so I can explain my issue more clearer?

Comment: ya come on conversation

Comment: Can you invite me to chat?

Comment: i dont know how to invite :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145547/discussion-between-user2911539-and-ravi).

Answer (score 0):

you can use convert in where clause as well as below:

```
WHERE convert(date, Start_Time) IN(SELECT DISTINCT CAST(Start_Time AS DATE) As Start_Time FROM Shift)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I've posted additional info above to try to clarify my issue. Can you please have a look?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to find jobs that start on a *particular* date, then I would recommend:

```
SELECT Job_Type
FROM Shift
WHERE CAST(Start_Time AS DATE) = '2017-05-26';
```

I don't understand what you want to do with the "IN".  You are saying:  "select all jobs that start on a date when any job starts".  That is the same as "select all jobs whose start date is known".

If you wanted days with only one job (a possibility suggested by the unnecessary `SELECT DISTINCT`), then you can do:

```
SELECT MAX(Job_Type) as Job_Type
FROM Shift
GROUP BY CAST(Start_Time AS DATE)
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Comment: Hi, For example: one table row has a _Job_Type_ of "Waiter" and the _Start_Time_ is Friday. Another row has a _Job_Type_ of "Driver" and a _Start_Time_ of Saturday. I want to display each job under their specified date.

Comment: @user2911539 . . . Order by the date.  Use the C# code to detect when a date changes and format the results accordingly.  What you specify in your comment is very different from what the question is asking.

Comment: OK, do you know how to pass the _Start_Time string below, into the SQL?  `string Start_time = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Start_Time").ToString();`                       
                `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Job_Type FROM Shift WHERE cast(Start_Time as date) IN (SELECT DISTINCT CAST(Start_Time AS DATE) As Start_Time FROM Shift)", con);`